# When I reenter item so it's old qty+ new qty in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, wamp

[image]

If I add 1 existing item name and quantity so it's append an existing quantity + new quantity how can I do? Please solved this error

```
$('#btn_add_item').click(function()
    {
        //alert('hello');
        var item_count = $('.items_table tbody tr').length + 1;
        var item_id = $('#my_items').val();
        var item_name = $('.custom-select a span').text();
        var item_price  = $('#bill_price').val();
        var item_qty = $('#bill_qty').val();
        var item_total = $('#bill_tprice').val();


        if(item_name != '')
        {
            var row = '<tr id="remove_'+item_count+'" class="item_count"><td><span id="edit_count">'+item_count+'</span></td><td>'+item_name+'</td><td><span id="existing_qty">'+item_qty+'</span><input type="text" name="edit_qty" id="edit_qty" value="'+item_qty+'" style="display:none;" onblur="change_item_price();"></td><td><span id="edit_price">'+item_price+'</span></td><td><span id="edit_total">'+item_total+'</span></td><td><a id="'+item_count+'" class="item_edit" onclick="myeditfun(this.id);">Edit</a></td><td><a id="'+item_count+'" class="item_remove" onclick="myclickfunc(this.id);">Remove</a></td></tr>';
            $('.items_table tbody').append(row);

            //alert(row);
                            $('.custom-select a span').text('');
                            $('#bill_price').val('');
                            $('#bill_qty').val('');
                            $('#bill_tprice').val('');

                            if()
                            {

                            }

                            //iterate through each td based on class and add the values
                            if(item_count == 1)
                            {

                                $('#value_total').text(item_total);
                                $('#bill_total_amount').val(item_total);
                            }
                            else{
                                var previous_value = $('#bill_total_amount').val();
                                var total_value = parseFloat(parseFloat(previous_value) + parseFloat(item_total));
                                $('#value_total').text(total_value);
                                $('#bill_total_amount').val(total_value);

                            }

                            $('.custom-select a').trigger('click');
        }
        else{
            alert('Please Select Item First');
        }       
            //alert(body_length);
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Match the entered name with the already existing names.
2. If there is a match then edit the already existing amounts (you should use OOP here where the edit function can just be called in here)
3. If no match then create a new line.

Matching the name means you need to get existing names, this can be done by looping over the second `<td>` of your table, should be relatively easy.